# What is the manner of inconsistency of Girard's paradox in Martin Lof type theory

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory

I am aware that assigning the type of Type to be Type (rather than stratifying to a hierarchy of types) leads to an inconsistency.  But does this inconsistency allow the construction of a well-typed term with no normal form, or does it actually allow a proof of False?  Are these two questions equivalent?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Girard's paradox constructs a non-normalizing proof of False.  You could read Hurken's "A simplification of Girard's paradox", or maybe Kevin Watkin's [formalization in Twelf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/research/hurkens95tlca.elf).

In general, these questions are not equivalent, though they often coincide.  A "reasonable" type theory will by inspection have no *normal* proofs of False, and so then normalization implies consistency.  The inverse (non-normalization => proof of False) is much less obvious, and it is certainly possible to construct reasonable paraconsistent type theories, where non-termination is confined under a monad and does not result in a proof of False.

Comment: Do you have any references for the kind of paraconsistent type theory that you mention here?

Comment: see work on the "Delay monad" for type theories where non-termination (and hence proof of False) is confined under a monad.

Answer (score 6):

It leads to a well-typed term, having no normal form, which is assigned the type False.  You can find the term given explicitly in [A simplification of Girard's paradox](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0014058)

Comment: Here's a free version of the linked paper: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/scans/hurkens95tlca.pdf